# What is the difference between Azure Service Bus and Service Bus 1.1?

Tags: azure, message-queue, azureservicebus, servicebus

From my understanding Service Bus 1.1 was released in 2013. Azure SB is much newer. I'm looking for documentation on SB 1.1 but I can only find the new docs for [Azure SB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview)

I recently joined a team that uses SB 1.1 and I'm very new to message queues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Service Bus (ASB) is a hosted cloud service. You do not run the broker locally but connect to a remote service. Service Bus for Windows Server (Service Bus 1.1 or SBWS) was an early on-premises broker offer for the customers that could not connect to Azure. Since then, SBWS was retired and is **no longer supported**. Microsoft has provided an ample time frame for customers to migrate away from SBWS.

> The product is available as a free download and will go out of mainstream support on January 9, 2018

([source](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/collaboration-and-federation-azure-service-bus-messaging-on-premises-futures/))

The team you've joined will have to act as they are running on an unsupported broker.